# Which datatype shall i use to store image in database(PostgreSQL)?

Tags: image, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL database. Here i need to store image into database which are many in numbers for example in thousands. So i need to know which datatype is to use "bytea" or 
"Large binary object"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general `bytea` is the better choice (I think).

The only advantage that "large objects"  have, is that you can access parts of the binary data through a streaming interface. Hardly anything you will ever need for images.